# prevent update operation globally in the application after evening 6.00 pm

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

i am developing a .net mvc app with entity framework and linq.
i need to prevent the application from handling update operation after evening 6.00 pm .
and release the update lock after morning 6.00 AM.

do we have any configuration in entity framework or in mvc design or in global.asax or in mvc filter to prevent database update operation in the application after 6.00 pm and releasing the update lock after morning 6.00 AM

Comment: When you say 'globally' do you actually mean the update operations that would affect domain Business Entities.  The reason I ask is because in most systems I've built or worked with (single DB) preventing updates to all tables would be problematic -- I'm thinking of things like logs, user profile, etc.

Comment: You may have a good "reason" for it, but websites that act like bricks-and-mortar operations (having "opening hours") can be incredibly frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

You could override the method `SaveChanges` of your context and do the intervall check inside.

See the following [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cc716714%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

```
public override int SaveChanges(SaveOptions options)
{
    if(DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.Hours < 6 || DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.Hours >= 18) {
    {
        throw new Exception("Changes to database are not allowed");
    } 
    else 
    {
        return base.SaveChanges(options);
    }
}
```